Unable to install TexLive from prebuilt template
I have the following devcontainer.json for GitHub codespaces:
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/debian
{
    "name": "Pandoc Development Container",
    // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:bullseye",

    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/rocker-org/devcontainer-features/quarto-cli:1": {
            "version": "latest",
            "installChromium": true
        },
        "ghcr.io/rocker-org/devcontainer-features/apt-packages:1": {
            "packages": "chromium"
        }, 
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/pandoc:1": {
            "version": "latest"
        }, 
        "ghcr.io/prulloac/devcontainer-features/latex:1": {
            "scheme": "full",
            "mirror": "https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/"
        }
    },
    "overrideFeatureInstallOrder": [
        "ghcr.io/rocker-org/devcontainer-features/apt-packages",
        "ghcr.io/rocker-org/devcontainer-features/quarto-cli",
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/pandoc",
        "ghcr.io/prulloac/devcontainer-features/latex"
    ]
}

Because the latex feature takes so long to build (~2 hours), I create a Codespace prebuild with it. This builds without issue.
However, when I try to start a Codespace container with it, I get the following error preventing creation:
#18 3.510 2024-04-23 20:59:00 (27.5 MB/s) - 'install-tl-unx.tar.gz' saved [5749656/5749656]
#18 3.510 
2024-04-23 20:59:01.745Z: #18 4.638 Loading https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
2024-04-23 20:59:03.570Z: #18 6.464 Installing TeX Live 2024 from: https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
#18 6.464 Platform: x86_64-linux => 'GNU/Linux on x86_64'
#18 6.464 Distribution: net  (downloading)
#18 6.464 Using URL: https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
2024-04-23 20:59:03.572Z: #18 6.464 Directory for temporary files: /tmp/0E9bT2_4wC
2024-04-23 20:59:03.694Z: #18 6.464 ./install-tl: No full, switching to scheme-minimal.
#18 6.533 Installing to: /usr/local/texlive/2024
#18 6.539 
#18 6.539 ./install-tl: DISK SPACE INSUFFICIENT!
#18 6.539 (7671 free < 100 reserve + installed 8366)
#18 6.539 Aborting installation.
#18 6.539   To skip the check, set the environment variable
#18 6.539   TEXLIVE_INSTALL_NO_DISKCHECK=1
2024-04-23 20:59:03.697Z: #18 6.587 ERROR: Feature "LaTeX Workshop" (ghcr.io/prulloac/devcontainer-features/latex) failed to install! Look at the documentation at ********/prulloac/devcontainer-features/tree/main/src/latex for help troubleshooting this error.
2024-04-23 20:59:04.000Z: #18 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c cp -ar /tmp/build-features-src/latex_3 /tmp/dev-container-features  && chmod -R 0755 /tmp/dev-container-features/latex_3  && cd /tmp/dev-container-features/latex_3  && chmod +x ./devcontainer-features-install.sh  && ./devcontainer-features-install.sh  && rm -rf /tmp/dev-container-features/latex_3" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
2024-04-23 20:59:04.210Z: ------
 > [dev_containers_target_stage 8/8] RUN --mount=type=bind,from=dev_containers_feature_content_source,source=latex_3,target=/tmp/build-features-src/latex_3     cp -ar /tmp/build-features-src/latex_3 /tmp/dev-container-features  && chmod -R 0755 /tmp/dev-container-features/latex_3  && cd /tmp/dev-container-features/latex_3  && chmod +x ./devcontainer-features-install.sh  && ./devcontainer-features-install.sh  && rm -rf /tmp/dev-container-features/latex_3:
6.464 Directory for temporary files: /tmp/0E9bT2_4wC
6.464 ./install-tl: No full, switching to scheme-minimal.
6.533 Installing to: /usr/local/texlive/2024
6.539 
6.539 ./install-tl: DISK SPACE INSUFFICIENT!
6.539 (7671 free < 100 reserve + installed 8366)
6.539 Aborting installation.
6.539   To skip the check, set the environment variable
6.539   TEXLIVE_INSTALL_NO_DISKCHECK=1
6.587 ERROR: Feature "LaTeX Workshop" (ghcr.io/prulloac/devcontainer-features/latex) failed to install! Look at the documentation at ********/prulloac/devcontainer-features/tree/main/src/latex for help troubleshooting this error.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the way the prebuild caches the latex packages occupying too much disk space? Any way to mitigate this error while still retaining the benefits of prebuilding a Codespace?
